# java.lang.NullPointerException on setOnClickListener in Fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment, sharedpreferences

I'm pretty new to Android and I'm trying to create an application that will score matches of the Vex Robotics Competition. I have a `ViewPager` with fragments for each team and i have a lot of buttons that increase and decrease numbers in `EditTexts`. I created an `OnClickListener` for each one. This code was working before I introduced `SharedPreferences` to carry values to the activity that calculates the score.

Fragment Code (sorry, there's a lot of it):

```
    package com.bearsandthings.vexskyrisescorer;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class BlueFragment extends Fragment {
        public static int bafloorgoal, bapost, bapostowned, baskyrisebuilt, baskyrisecubes;
        public static int bdfloorgoal, bdpost, bdpostowned, bdskyrisebuilt, bdskyrisecubes;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);


            //AUTONOMOUS
            bafloorgoal = 0;
            bapost = 0;
            bapostowned = 0;
            baskyrisebuilt = 0;
            baskyrisecubes = 0;
            bdfloorgoal = 0;
            bdpost = 0;
            bdpostowned = 0;
            bdskyrisebuilt = 0;
            bdskyrisecubes = 0;

            final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.bearsandthings.vexskyrisescorer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putInt("bafloorgoal", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bapost", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bapostowned", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("baskyrisebuilt", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("baskyrisecubes", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bdfloorgoal", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bdpost", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bdpostowned", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bdskyrisebuilt", 0).apply();
            prefs.edit().putInt("bdskyrisecubes", 0).apply();

            Button rAFloorGoalUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAFloorGoalUp);
            rAFloorGoalUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rAFloorGoal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAFloorGoal);
                    int testnum = Integer.valueOf(rAFloorGoal.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 22)
                    {
                        testnum += 1;
                        bafloorgoal = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bafloorgoal",testnum).apply();

                        rAFloorGoal.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });
            Button rAFloorGoalDown = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAFloorGoalDn);
            rAFloorGoalDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rAFloorGoal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAFloorGoal);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rAFloorGoal.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bafloorgoal = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bafloorgoal",testnum).apply();
                        rAFloorGoal.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rAPostUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPostUp);
            rAPostUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rAPost = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPost);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rAPost.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 22)
                    {
                        testnum +=1;
                        bapost = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bapost",testnum).apply();
                        rAPost.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rAPostDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPostDn);
            rAPostDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rAPost = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPost);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rAPost.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bapost = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bapost", testnum).apply();
                        rAPost.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rAPostOwnedUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPostOwnedUp);
            rAPostOwnedUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rAPostOwned = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPostOwned);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rAPostOwned.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 10)
                    {
                        testnum +=1;
                        bapostowned = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bapost", testnum).apply();
                        rAPostOwned.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rAPostOwnedDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPostOwnedDn);
            rAPostOwnedDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rAPostOwned = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAPostOwned);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rAPostOwned.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum >0 )
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bapostowned = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bapostowned", testnum).apply();
                        rAPostOwned.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rASkyriseBuiltUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseBuiltUp);
            rASkyriseBuiltUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rASkyriseBuilt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseBuilt);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rASkyriseBuilt.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 7)
                    {
                        testnum += 1;
                        baskyrisebuilt = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("baskyrisebuilt", testnum).apply();
                        rASkyriseBuilt.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rASkyriseBuiltDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseBuiltDn);
            rASkyriseBuiltDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rASkyriseBuilt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseBuilt);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rASkyriseBuilt.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -= 1;
                        baskyrisebuilt = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("baskyrisebuilt", testnum).apply();
                        rASkyriseBuilt.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });
            Button rASkyriseCubesUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseCubesUp);
            rASkyriseCubesUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rASkyriseCubes = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseCubes);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rASkyriseCubes.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 22)
                    {
                        testnum +=1;
                        baskyrisecubes = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("baskyrisecubes", testnum).apply();
                        rASkyriseCubes.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rASkyriseCubesDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseCubesDn);
            rASkyriseCubesDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rASkyriseCubes = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rASkyriseCubes);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rASkyriseCubes.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        baskyrisecubes = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("baskyrisecubes", testnum).apply();
                        rASkyriseCubes.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });


            // DRIVER CONTROL

            Button rDFloorGoalUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDFloorGoalUp);
            rDFloorGoalUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDFloorGoal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDFloorGoal);
                    int testnum = Integer.valueOf(rDFloorGoal.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 22)
                    {
                        testnum += 1;
                        bdfloorgoal = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdfloorgoal", testnum).apply();
                        rDFloorGoal.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });
            Button rDFloorGoalDown = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDFloorGoalDn);
            rDFloorGoalDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDFloorGoal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDFloorGoal);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDFloorGoal.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bdfloorgoal = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdfloorgoal", testnum).apply();
                        rDFloorGoal.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rDPostUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPostUp);
            rDPostUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDPost = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPost);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDPost.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 22)
                    {
                        testnum +=1;
                        bdpost = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdpost", testnum).apply();
                        rDPost.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rDPostDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPostDn);
            rDPostDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDPost = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPost);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDPost.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bdpost = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdpost", testnum).apply();
                        rDPost.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rDPostOwnedUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPostOwnedUp);
            rDPostOwnedUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDPostOwned = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPostOwned);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDPostOwned.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 10)
                    {
                        testnum +=1;
                        bdpostowned = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdpostowned", testnum).apply();
                        rDPostOwned.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rDPostOwnedDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPostOwnedDn);
            rDPostOwnedDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDPostOwned = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDPostOwned);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDPostOwned.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum >0 )
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bdpostowned = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdpostowned", testnum).apply();
                        rDPostOwned.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }

                }

            });

            Button rDSkyriseBuiltUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseBuiltUp);
            rDSkyriseBuiltUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDSkyriseBuilt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseBuilt);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDSkyriseBuilt.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 7)
                    {
                        testnum += 1;
                        bdskyrisebuilt = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdskyrisebuilt", testnum).apply();
                        rDSkyriseBuilt.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rDSkyriseBuiltDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseBuiltDn);
            rDSkyriseBuiltDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDSkyriseBuilt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseBuilt);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDSkyriseBuilt.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -= 1;
                        bdskyrisebuilt = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdskyrisebuilt", testnum).apply();
                        rDSkyriseBuilt.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });
            Button rDSkyriseCubesUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseCubesUp);
            rDSkyriseCubesUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDSkyriseCubes = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseCubes);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDSkyriseCubes.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum < 22)
                    {
                        testnum +=1;
                        bdskyrisecubes = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdskyrisecubes", testnum).apply();
                        rDSkyriseCubes.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rDSkyriseCubesDn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseCubesDn);
            rDSkyriseCubesDn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText rDSkyriseCubes = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rDSkyriseCubes);
                    int testnum = Integer.parseInt(rDSkyriseCubes.getText().toString());
                    if (testnum > 0)
                    {
                        testnum -=1;
                        bdskyrisecubes = testnum;
                        prefs.edit().putInt("bdskyrisecubes", testnum).apply();
                        rDSkyriseCubes.setText(String.valueOf(testnum));
                    }
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }


    }
```

LogCat:

```
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at com.bearsandthings.vexskyrisescorer.BlueFragment.onCreateView(BlueFragment.java:48)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12729)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12729)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12729)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2098)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12729)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2453)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:3151)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:2918)
05-30 22:04:05.827: E/AndroidRuntime(16083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That call stack will tell you precisely what line throws the exception and debugging the app will tell you precisely what object is null. Once we have that information, if you can't figure out why the object is null we can probably help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `fragment_blue.xml` layout. Your `Button` with id `rAFloorGoalUp` needs to be declared in this file.

When it isn't

```
Button rAFloorGoalUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rAFloorGoalUp);
```

will be assigned `null` and

```
rAFloorGoalUp.setOnClickListener(...)
```

will raise a `NullPointerException` error.

Comment: Oh wow fail I forgot to change all the "r"s to "b"s when i copy-pasted. Thanks so much. User error :P